# Updating tables of different access database through one access application

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having 4-10 access database application which all has employee access table. Is there any way to update these employee tables through one access application rather than going to each every application and adding employees or updating the employee details.

Is it really possible? Every suggestion will be valuable.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and you have several choices how to update all the others. The easiest is to link that table from each database to your 'primary' database (yes, you would need to provide an alternate name to avoid duplicates). Then add some VBA code so that when an update in the primary occurs, it updates each of the other db's. The other method is to not use linked tables, but to use VBA to open the other database tables and do the update. How is the update taking place now? A form?

Comment: Usually go into the tables and update the records manually.

Comment: If the tables are in Access and not SQL Server, then there is no trigger for manual table updates. Your choices are limited to either creating a form to do the update - which would give you VBA access to the events, or writing a 'monitor' program to 'always' check for changes (DateAdd / DateChange timestamps required in table) - or you could check at some timer interval. If all updates need to occur immediately then I suggest the form approach.

Comment: Yes its in Access, I will have to try the form approach.Thanks @WayneG.Dunn

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn If the different database I wanted to update is protected using password. Will it be a problem updating the tables from another access application.

Comment: If you try to LINK the tables to the other database, you will be prompted for the password, which will be saved. If you use VBA for the updates and connect 'on-the-fly', you can specify the password in the connect string.